# How can I see aggregates over the traces in New Relic

Tags: performance, newrelic

We use New Relic to gather performance information from our production environment and we have  added some custom instrumentation. In the Web Transactions screens, we can see which transactions use most time and we can even drill down into the specific traces of the slowest transactions. This is all working fine. However, the slowest transactions are not always representative for the operation as a whole. They are often edge cases (cache expired, warming requests after an update, etc...).

I would be interested to see the very same data that we can see in the Trace Details in a more aggregate way. Preferably also in the hierarchical way that is used in Trace Details (although this will not always be possible, as multiple instances may have different traces). Is the Breakdown Table on the overview page for one Web Transaction type actually what I am looking for? I am not sure. What does that show exactly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Breakdown Table in New Relic's Web Transactions tab is designed to give you an aggregate of performance data along with historical comparisons.  This may not provide the specific level of detail you're looking for.

New Relic has a new feature available for the Python and Java agents called X-Ray Sessions.  After you start an x-ray session, New Relic will collect up to 100 transaction traces and a thread profile for your transaction. Collection automatically stops at 100 traces or 24 hours, whichever comes first.  The results are displayed in a hierarchical waterfall chart like transaction traces, but the data is aggregated.  Here is an overview:

https://newrelic.com/docs/transactions-dashboards/xray-sessions

While I can't say if or when this feature will be rolled out to the other language agents, I suggest keeping an eye the following for updates:

https://newrelic.com/docs/features/new-noteworthy

Comment: And do I understand correctly that these X-Ray session collect traces ad random and not just the slow ones? Then it is very much what I hoped for. Too bad we are on the .NET platform, but I'll wait.

Comment: Thread profiles could actually also be a fit for our requirement. But also just for java and python. :(